# JavaScript SideNav OneButton Toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle

I manage to get the sidenav to open but can't get it to close. I've read that using conditionals is the way to go but here it isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Here is my code:

```js
var sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
var page = document.getElementById("page");

function togNav() {
  if (sidenav.style.width = '0px') {
    sidenav.style.width = "200px";
    page.style.marginLeft = "200px";
  } else {
    sidenav.style.width = "0px";
    page.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.openbtn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidenav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidenav a {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0.1px #ddd solid;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: helvetica neue;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

#page {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <button id="openbtn" class="openbtn" onclick="togNav()">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: == for compare = to set (in your if statement)

Comment: How did i miss that!!!
THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If condition was wrong. You are using `=` (assignment) instead use `==` for comparison

```js
var sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
var page = document.getElementById("page");

function togNav() {
  if (sidenav.style.width == '0px') { // here
    sidenav.style.width = "200px";
    page.style.marginLeft = "200px";
  } else {
    sidenav.style.width = "0px";
    page.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.openbtn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidenav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidenav a {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0.1px #ddd solid;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: helvetica neue;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

#page {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <button id="openbtn" class="openbtn" onclick="togNav()">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```